# Creating a DataFrame from a 2-D list where the 3 elements of the 2nd axis are the row index, col name, and cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2-dimensional list in the following format:

```
[
    [1, 10, 3],
    [1, 11, 2],
    [1, 12, 5],
    [2, 11, 3],
    [2, 12, 1],
    [2, 13, 4]
]
```

I would now like to make a pandas DF where the first number of each internal list is the row index, the second number is the column name, and the 3rd number is the given cell's value (which is set to 0 if that column doesn't exists for that row)

```
     10    11    12    13
1     3     2     5     0 
2     0     3     1     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to dataframe and use pivot table i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame(li).pivot_table(index=0,columns=1,values=2,fill_value=0)

1   10   11   12   13
0                    
1  3.0  2.0  5.0  0.0
2  0.0  3.0  1.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index([0,1])[2].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
1  10  11  12  13
0                
1   3   2   5   0
2   0   3   1   4
```

If solution above failed because non unique index with columns pairs is necessary aggregate by[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`:

```
a = [
    [1, 10, 3], <- 1,10
    [1, 10, 2], <- 1,10
    [1, 12, 5],
    [2, 11, 3],
    [2, 12, 1],
    [2, 13, 4]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a).groupby([0,1])[2].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
1   10   11   12   13
0                    
1  2.5  0.0  5.0  0.0 <- (2+3)/2 = 2.5
2  0.0  3.0  1.0  4.0
```